# Select gets double options after submit form modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, bootstrap-modal

I got a problem with a bootstrap modal form and dynamic select options.

- When I open the modal, there is an input and two select options.
- One select is populating the second after a user check an option from
  the first select.

On the first load, the select options are working ok. 
When I submit the form (with Save button) and I reopen the modal, the first select gets the correct options but the second got double options.
When I reload the page everything gets back to normal until I submit the form again.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('table.setting-groups');
    var table_permissions = $('table.settings-groups-permissions');
    var table_permissions_edit = $('table.settings-groups-permissions-edit');
    var permissions = [];
    var dataArray = [];

    $('#addGroupModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('select#permission_category').each(function () {
            var $select = $(this);
            $select.empty().append('<option></option>');

            $.ajax({
                url: $select.attr('data-source')
            }).then(function (options) {
                options.map(function (option) {
                    var $option = $('<option>');
                    $option
                        .val(option[$select.attr('data-valueKey')])
                        .text(option[$select.attr('data-displayKey')]);
                    $select.append($option);
                });
            });
        });

        $('select#permission_category').change(function () {
            var category = $('select#permission_category').val();
            if (category !== '') {
                $('select#permission_category_description').each(function () {
                    var $select = $(this);
                    $select.empty().append('<option></option>');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: $select.attr('data-source'),
                        data: {category: category}
                    }).then(function (options) {
                        options.map(function (option) {
                            var $option = $('<option>');
                            $option
                                .val(option[$select.attr('data-valueKey')])
                                .text(option[$select.attr('data-displayKey')]);
                            $select.append($option);
                        });
                    });
                });
            } else {
                $('select#permission_category_description')[0].empty();
            }
        });

        $('select#permission_category_description').change(function () {
            var category = $('select#permission_category').val();
            var description = $('select#permission_category_description').val();
            var check = $.inArray(description, permissions) > -1;

            if (!check) {
                permissions.push(description);
                table_permissions.DataTable().row.add({
                    "category": category,
                    "description": description
                }).draw();
            }
        });
        // Save permissions
        $('form#add-group').submit(function (e) {
            $('#savebtn').button('loading');
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            // Push table data (permissions) to form for submit
            $('<input>').attr({
                type: 'hidden',
                id: 'permissions',
                name: 'permissions',
                value: permissions
            }).appendTo(form);

            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: form.attr('method'),
                data: new FormData(this),
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#addGroupModal').modal('toggle');
                    swal(
                        'Επιβεβαίωση Καταχώριση',
                        'Η ομάδα δικαιωμάτων καταχωρήθηκε επιτυχώς',
                        'success'
                    ).then(function () {
                        permissions = [];
                        dataArray = [];
                        form[0].reset();
                        $('select#permission_category_description').empty();
                        table_permissions.DataTable().destroy();
                        table.DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    });
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    swal(
                        'Αποτυχία Καταχώρισης',
                        data.responseText,
                        'error'
                    )
                }
            });
        });
        // Remove row when you click X
        table_permissions.on('click', '.delete', function () {
            table_permissions.DataTable().row('.selected').remove().draw(false);
        });
    });

    $('#addGroupModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        // Clean forms / select / datatables / arrays on modal close
        $('select#permission_category_description').empty();
        $('form')[0].reset();
        table_permissions.DataTable().destroy();
        permissions = [];
        dataArray = [];
    });

    $('#editGroupModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');

        $.post('../../custom/json/groups.php?view', {id: id}, function (arr) {
            $('input#group_name').val(arr.description);
            // Get existing permissions from groups
            dataArray = arr.data.map(function (value) {
                return value.description;
            });
        });

        $('select#permission_category_edit').each(function () {
            var $select = $(this);
            $select.empty().append('<option></option>');

            $.ajax({
                url: $select.attr('data-source')
            }).then(function (options) {
                options.map(function (option) {
                    var $option = $('<option>');
                    $option
                        .val(option[$select.attr('data-valueKey')])
                        .text(option[$select.attr('data-displayKey')]);
                    $select.append($option);
                });
            });
        });

        $('select#permission_category_edit').change(function () {
            var category = $('select#permission_category_edit').val();
            if (category !== '') {
                $('select#permission_category_description_edit').each(function () {
                    var $select = $(this);
                    $select.empty().append('<option></option>');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: $select.attr('data-source'),
                        data: {category: category}
                    }).then(function (options) {
                        options.map(function (option) {
                            var $option = $('<option>');
                            $option
                                .val(option[$select.attr('data-valueKey')])
                                .text(option[$select.attr('data-displayKey')]);
                            $select.append($option);
                        });
                    });
                });
            } else {
                $('select#permission_category_description_edit')[0].empty();
            }
        });

        $('select#permission_category_description_edit').change(function () {
            var category = $('select#permission_category_edit').val();
            var description = $('select#permission_category_description_edit').val();
            permissions = dataArray;
            var check = $.inArray(description, permissions) > -1;

            if (!check) {
                permissions.push(description);
                table_permissions_edit.DataTable().row.add({
                    "category": category,
                    "description": description
                }).draw();
            }
        });

        var settingGroupsPermissionsEdit = {
            "destroy": true,
            "processing": true,
            "deferRender": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "select": true ,
            "searching": false,
            "paging": false,
            "info": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "language": {
                "url": "/custom/js/data-tables/Greek.json"
            },
            "ajax": "../../custom/json/groups.php?view&id=" + id,
            "dataSrc": "data",
            "columns": [
                {data: "category", className: "text-center"},
                {data: "description", className: "text-center"},
                {
                    data: null, className: "text-center btn-actions", render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<a data-id="' + data.description + '" class="danger p-0 delete"><i class="ft-x font-medium-3 mr-2"></i></a>';
                    }
                }
            ]
        };

        $('table.settings-groups-permissions-edit').DataTable($.extend(true, {}, settingGroupsPermissionsEdit, {}));
        // Save permissions
        $('form#edit-group').submit(function (e) {
            $('#editbtn').button('loading');
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            // Push table data (permissions) to form for submit
            $('<input>').attr({
                type: 'hidden',
                id: 'permissions',
                name: 'permissions',
                value: permissions
            }).appendTo(form);

            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action') + '&id=' + id,
                type: form.attr('method'),
                data: new FormData(this),
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#editGroupModal').modal('toggle');
                    swal(
                        'Επιβεβαίωση Ενημέρωσης',
                        'Η ομάδα δικαιωμάτων ενημερώθηκε επιτυχώς',
                        'success'
                    ).then(function () {
                        permissions = [];
                        dataArray = [];
                        form[0].reset();
                        $('select#permission_category_description_edit').empty();
                        table_permissions_edit.DataTable().destroy();
                        table.DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    });
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    swal(
                        'Αποτυχία Ενημέρωσης',
                        data.responseText,
                        'error'
                    )
                }
            });
        });
        // Remove row when you click X
        table_permissions_edit.on('click', '.delete', function () {
            var row_desc = table_permissions_edit.DataTable().rows('.selected').data().pluck('description')[0];
            permissions = remove(permissions, row_desc); // remove element from posted permissions array
            table_permissions_edit.DataTable().row('.selected').remove().draw();
        });
    });

    $('#editGroupModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        // Clean forms / select / datatables / arrays on modal close
        $('select#permission_category_description_edit').empty();
        $('form')[0].reset();
        table_permissions_edit.DataTable().destroy();
        permissions = [];
        dataArray = [];
    });
    // Delete group
    table.on('click', '.swal-delete', function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        swal({
            title: 'Διαγραφή',
            text: 'Είστε σίγουρος/η οτι θέλετε να διαγράψετε την ομάδα δικαιωμάτων;',
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#0CC27E',
            cancelButtonColor: '#FF586B',
            confirmButtonText: 'Ναι',
            cancelButtonText: 'Όχι'
        }).then(function (isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                $.post("../../custom/json/groups.php?delete", {id: id}, function (data) {
                    swal(
                        'Επιβεβαίωση Διαγραφής',
                        'Η ομάδα δικαιωμάτων διαγράφηκε επιτυχώς',
                        'success'
                    ).then(function () {
                        table.DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    });
                });
            }
        }).catch(swal.noop);
    });
    // Remove element from an array
    function remove(array, value) {
        return array.filter(function (element) {
            return element !== value;
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- BEGIN ADD GROUP MODAL-->
<div class="modal fade text-left" id="addGroupModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addGroupModal" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="add-group" action="/custom/json/groups.php?add" method="post" class="form form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-header bg-medi white">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="addGroupModal"><i class="ft-list font-medium-3 mr-2"></i> Προσθήκη Νέας Ομάδας</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body mt-1">
                    <fieldset class="form-group floating-label-form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-4 label-control mt-1" for="group_name">Όνομα Ομάδας: </label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" id="group_name" class="form-control" name="group_name">
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group floating-label-form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-4 label-control" for="permission_category">Κατηγορία</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <select id="permission_category" name="permission_category" class="form-control"
                                    data-source="/custom/json/groups.php?permission-category"
                                    data-valueKey="category"
                                    data-displayKey="category">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group floating-label-form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-4 label-control" for="permission_category_description">Πρόσβαση</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <select id="permission_category_description" name="permission_category_description" class="form-control"
                                    data-source="/custom/json/groups.php?permission-description"
                                    data-valueKey="description"
                                    data-displayKey="description">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-sm base-style table-hover full-width settings-groups-permissions">
                            <thead class="bg-medi text-white text-center">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Κατηγορία</th>
                                <th>Πρόσβαση</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Κλείσιμο</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-medi white" id="savebtn" data-loading-text="Αποθήκευση...">Αποθήκευση</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END ADD GROUP MODAL-->
<!-- BEGIN EDIT GROUP MODAL-->
<div class="modal fade text-left" id="editGroupModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editGroupModal" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="edit-group" action="/custom/json/groups.php?edit" method="post" class="form form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-header bg-medi white">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="editGroupModal"><i class="ft-list font-medium-3 mr-2"></i> Επεξεργασία Ομάδας</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body mt-1">
                    <fieldset class="form-group floating-label-form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-4 label-control mt-1" for="group_name">Όνομα Ομάδας: </label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" id="group_name" class="form-control" name="group_name" disabled>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group floating-label-form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-4 label-control" for="permission_category_edit">Κατηγορία</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <select id="permission_category_edit" name="permission_category" class="form-control"
                                    data-source="/custom/json/groups.php?permission-category"
                                    data-valueKey="category"
                                    data-displayKey="category">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group floating-label-form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-4 label-control" for="permission_category_description_edit">Πρόσβαση</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <select id="permission_category_description_edit" name="permission_category_description" class="form-control"
                                    data-source="/custom/json/groups.php?permission-description"
                                    data-valueKey="description"
                                    data-displayKey="description">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-sm base-style table-hover full-width settings-groups-permissions-edit">
                            <thead class="bg-medi text-white text-center">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Κατηγορία</th>
                                <th>Πρόσβαση</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Κλείσιμο</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-medi white" id="editbtn" data-loading-text="Αποθήκευση...">Αποθήκευση</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END EDIT GROUP MODAL-->
```

Any suggestions ? I can't find where is the issue that causes js to run twice on select populate options.
Thank you in advance

**UPDATE:** The 2nd select option is doubled on modal show not on form submit.

Comment: I empty the $select on Line 4

Comment: You need to empty the select as well for the second select box.
From: $select.append($option); -> $select.empty().append($option);

Comment: I updated the js code on my question

Comment: Sounds like your ".on('<event>', ....)" -callbacks are stacking up. Check your code on how many times you run over each "on" -method call. To clear the binding you can use the jquery-off-method as decribed here: https://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you bind `$('select#permission_category').change` inside `$('#addGroupModal').on('shown.bs.modal'` handler so each time your modal show, it will bind `$('select#permission_category').change` another time. That's why when you open the modal second time, the 2nd select option is doubled and will be tripled on third time...

You can solve it by:

Option 1: Move `$('select#permission_category').change` to be outside of `$('#addGroupModal').on('shown.bs.modal'` handler.

Option 2: Remove `$('select#permission_category')` change handler using [.off()](https://api.jquery.com/off/) when closing modal or before bind it in `$('#addGroupModal').on('shown.bs.modal'` handler.

Option 3: Create all options first then use [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) instead of `.append()` to set the html contents of select (this still bind change multiple time but the options is not multipled)

Comment: Tried Option 1, but its not helpfull. On Option 2 I added `$('select#permission_category').off()` and `$('select#permission_category_description').off().empty()` and It worked !! Thank you all

Comment: I'm glad it helped.